# Output data from array in a certain order based on data in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am pushing list items into an array which have a data-sort value on them. When calling them back from the array I need to output them in their data-sort order where 1 would come first, 2 second, and so on. **However** if the data-sort is equal to 0, I need to do something completely different with the item.

**JS**

```
var arr = [];
$('ul li').each(function() {
  arr.push($(this));
});

$('ul.main').html('');
$.each(arr, function (i) {
  var item = arr[i];
  var content = $(item).html();
  var itemSort = $(item).data('sort'); //Need to sort by this value
  if(itemSort != '0') {
    $('ul.main').append('<li>' + content + '</li>')
  } else {
    $('.another-list').append('<li>' + content + '</li>'); // Sort order of 0's doesn't matter
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="main">
  <li data-sort="3">Item 1</li>
  <li data-sort="2">Item 2</li>
  <li data-sort="1">Item 3</li>
  <li data-sort="0">Item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="another-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Does your code produce errors? If so please edit your question adding the errors. Your question seems like it's about to describe the troubles you're having, but then it just hits a brick wall.

Comment: @JonnyHenly right now there is no code in there to actually control the order in which the data is output from the array, so no errors yet. I am not sure how to even use javascript/jQuery to sort by data within the array.

Comment: BTW, why do you push the element into "contactOptions" and then use "arr" in the "each" function ?

Comment: Is `contactOption` in the third line supposed to read `arr`?

Comment: yes, just changed that, sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The need to create an array from the selected elements is redundant as a jQuery object *is* an array of the selected elements.

Also, the need to take the `html()` of an `li` and then create that in an entirely new `li` is redundant as you can move elements from one list to another by just using `append()`.

With that in mind you can massively simplify your code by using a combination of `sort()` and `filter()`:

```
$('li').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data('sort') > $(b).data('sort');
}).appendTo('.main').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('sort') == 0;
}).appendTo('.another-list');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rd62fw8a/)

Comment: This is why we pay you the big money(I hope). Thank you for helping me think of this in a more simple manner!

Comment: I wish ;) Glad to help